# Creating a chi square function in lisp. [beginner]

Tags: lisp, chi-squared

First off I apologize for such a beginner question.
My goal is not just to create a chi square function, but to understand how to avoid the general problem I am experiencing.

My code looks like this:

```
(defun chi-square (expected-list observed-list)
(cond ((not (= (length expected-list) (length observed-list))) (print "Lists do not match in length.~%"))
    ((and (null expected-list) (null observed-list)) 0)
    (+ (/ (square (- (car observed-list) (car expected-list))) (car expected-list)) 
       (chi-square (cdr expected-list) (cdr observed-list)))
)
)
```

The third condition is working fine I think, except when it calls chi-square on nil and nil the output just reads 0. I understand why this is happening (because of the second condition), but I don't know how to avoid it. For example if I give it an expected-list of (100 50) and an observed-list of (90 60) I want it to output (+ 1 (+ 2 0)) = 3. How can I give (chi-square nil nil) a value of 0 without just ending the function right then and there?

disclaimer: I am sure there are better ways to do this, and maybe functions that already do this. I am only writing this function for learning purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the third `cond` case: `t` is missing before the sum:

```
(defun chi-square (expected-list observed-list)
  (cond ((not (= (length expected-list) (length observed-list)))
         (print "Lists do not match in length.~%"))
        ((and (null expected-list) (null observed-list)) 0)
        (t (+ (/ (square (- (car observed-list) (car expected-list))) (car expected-list))
              (chi-square (cdr expected-list) (cdr observed-list))))))
```

You can find the syntax of the `cond` macro in the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm#cond).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general you want to avoid calling something like `length` inside of procedure where you are recursing down the same list.  That's because run-time of `length` is proportional to the length of the list you give it, and you'll end up with a O(N^2) algorithm because you call it on every tail of the original list.  Which is OK if your list are always short.  Better to test the list lengths just once at the beginning of the routine, or bail out at the end when one of the list is `null` and the other isn't.  Anyway, here are a few other way to write that function:

```
;using built-in recursion combinators (mapcar & reduce)
(defun χ² (expected observed)
  (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (e o) (/ (square (- o e)) e)) expected observed)))

;using loop
(defun chi-sqr (expected observed)
  (loop
     for e in expected
     for o in observed
     summing (/ (square (- o e)) e)))
```